# How to encrypt data for specific columns in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, security, encryption

I am exploring to encrypt data in mysql of specific columns. I stumbled upon the AES_ECRYPT() and AES_DECRYPT() function but the problem is that I am using Hibernate in java and the @ColumnTransformer annotation needs the value to be constant, i.e. available at compile time. But I know its not a good practice to hardcode the key from the same server so I want to store it in an external server and get the key through API. But how do I make that work with the @ColumnTransformer ?

Should I instead encrypt and decrypt at application level only and store the encrypted data as varchar in mysql? Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that fetching the key through an API call is not an optimal solution. Consider what would happen in case the key retrieval API is unavailable. That case would hinder your application's correct behavior. I agree that hard-coding value is not the correct thing to do.

What you could is to either expose the key through a configuration property of either the application or the database (if supported). Also you can workaround the need for constant values at annotations  using Spel to invoke a method that returns your required value dynamically.

Comment: but as far as I read about encryption, its a bad practice to keep the keys on the same server.